# Do mirrors exist for restricted, multiverse and universe repos?

Tags: repository, mirrors

As far as I know, [this page on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)  contains the *de-facto* list of 
**Official Archive Mirrors for Ubuntu**.

But all the mirrors available there contain only `main` repository.

So where are the restricted, multiverse and universe repos? Are they not mirrored or is the list available somewhere else or something else?

Comment: Click on the mirror and go to the "pool" directory. You will see more than just "main". eg. [very first mirror pool directory](http://mirror.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/ubuntu/pool/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those repository components (restricted, multiverse and universe) are also mirrored by the mirrors listed on the page. Once you choose a mirror, you can just append `universe multiverse restricted` to the `deb` and `deb-src` lines.

Comment: So why is is not shown there? is it just assumed to be there?

Comment: Possibly. I think it could be because Launchpad is just checking the freshness of the `main` pocket, and so is only displaying that pocket.